# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: yourOrders when I try display an array from FireStore in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a array that are pushed in JSON format to firestore and when I receive it I convert it to string and print it on console it gaves me this output

```
["[{\"image\":\"https://static.producer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/02170807/07-3-col-beans-GettyImages-157280488.jpg\",\"name\":\"Beans\",\"price\":45,\"quantityToOrder\":1,\"id\":1,\"total\":45},{\"res\":\"45\"}]"]
```

But when I try displaying with this code it gaves me this error

```
firestore()
.collection('vegezoneData')
.doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
.get()
.then((documentSnapshot) => {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    var yourOrders = documentSnapshot.data().MyOrders; 
    JSON.stringify(yourOrders);
    console.log(yourOrders);
  }
});
return (
<View> 
  <Text>{yourOrders}</Text>
  <View style={styles.tableProducts}>
    <Text style={styles.productColumn}>{yourOrders}</Text> 
  </View>
```

This is my error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variabl`enter code here`e: yourOrders
```

I really hope that you helps me I've tried a lot of options but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an asynchronous operation in your component. That means that before the `then()` part is properly fetched, your data will not be immediately available. You should do two things:

1. Your variable `yourOrders` should be managed by state. You can easily do this with the state hook. You just need a setter function `setYourOrders` that wil populate your `yourOrders` variable, once the data is fetched.
2. You must check in your `return` statement to see if `yourOrders` has some data. If not, you should include some kind of an indicator, that the data is still being fetched.

I assume you are using a functional component in this case. You can write the following component like so:

```js
const Component = () => {
    const [yourOrders, setYourOrders] = useState([]);
    firestore()
    .collection('vegezoneData')
    .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then((documentSnapshot) => {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        var yourOrders = documentSnapshot.data().MyOrders; 
        JSON.stringify(yourOrders);
        setYourOrders(yourOrders);
        console.log(yourOrders);
      }
    });
    return (yourOrders && yourOrders.length > 0 ?
    <View> 
      <Text>{yourOrders}</Text>
      <View style={styles.tableProducts}>
        <Text style={styles.productColumn}>{yourOrders}</Text> 
      </View>
    </View>
      : 
    <View>
       <Text>Loading...</Text>
    </View>
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are declaring yourOrders inside documentSnapshot callback. And in JSX {yourOrders} couldn't be found. The issue is in JSX:

```
documentSnapshot.data().MyOrders;
```

And you are creating it inside the callback, which will call after some time but in the initial render, it won't be declared.

```
 var yourOrders = documentSnapshot.data().MyOrders;
```

If you are using hooks, try to create a variable with useState. Like so:

```
const [yourOrders, setYourOrders] = useState(null);
```

And set it in snapshot callback:

```
setYourOrders(documentSnapshot.data().MyOrders);
```